sympy simplify expression with power-reduction formula
I have the following sympy expression
>>> a

         ⎛2⋅π⋅(x - y)⎞
2 - 2⋅cos ───────────
         ⎝     P     ⎠

which I would like to simplify to

     2 ⎛π⋅(x - y)⎞
4⋅sin   ─────────
       ⎝    P    ⎠

by using the (inverse) of the first power-reduction formula listed in Wikipedia.
The second form involves only 6 operations, versus the 7 operations of the first form, but when I use the fu function from sympy.simplify trying to minimize the number of operations I get:
>>> fu(a, measure=lambda x: x.count_ops())


         ⎛2⋅π⋅(x - y)⎞
2 - 2⋅cos ───────────
         ⎝     P     ⎠

or at best
>>> fu(sympy.expand_trig(a), measure=lambda x: x.count_ops())


         2⎛π⋅(x - y)⎞
4 - 4⋅cos  ─────────
          ⎝    P    ⎠

which still involves 7 operations.
Is there anyway to convince sympy to output the sin**2 form?

You can have finer control by selecting the desired transformation from fu
>>> from sympy import S
>>> from sympy.simplify.fu import TR11,TR6
>>> TR6(TR11(S('2 - 2*cos(2*pi*(x - y)/p)')))
4*sin(pi*(x - y)/p)**2


Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted! I did try to explore the individual functions in the fu module but hadn't arrived at the right combination.

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but if you replace the inside with 2b, where b is a symbol, it will reduce.
x, y, P, b = symbols("x y P b")
a = 2 - 2*cos(2*b)
new_a = fu(a, measure=lambda x: x.count_ops()).subs(b, 2*pi*(x-y)/P)

I think the optimizer is getting confused with the terms inside changing the number of operations depending on how they're written.
